# Cut a string in a Django template that's returned by request.post

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to cut the string that's returned by `request.post` in a template:

E.g.:

I access the url `/foo/bar/long/` and now

```
{% if request.path[:8] == '/foo/bar' %}...{endif}
```

shoud be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a built-in template filter called [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{% if request.path|slice:':8' == '/foo/bar' %}...{endif}
```

Comment: Thank you, also for the reference!